# How many experiments for measuring of standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation

I want to get standard deviation of variable. How many data I need to to obtain correct value?

What is correct approach to estimate amount of data I need?

What precision I need to say it is precise enough?

Comment: By "experiments", do you simply mean how much data do you need? Are your data normally distributed? How much precision do you need?

Comment: @gung I edited my question

Comment: "Enough" is subjective, and "correct" is impossible.  The following will give you an idea of the sampling distribution of the standard deviation:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation